# Raycast BCE0044 found expecting ), found 'hit'

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

I'm making RTS dynamic camera using Raycast, but my it is causing these problems:

```
 1. Assets/CameraMover.js(11,73): BCE0044: expecting ), found 'hit'.
 2. Assets/CameraMover.js(11,77): BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).
```

code looks like this:

```
var RaycastHit : hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(Transform.position, -Transform.position, out hit)){
    curDistance = Vector3.Distance(Transform.position, hit.point);
}

if(curDistance != cameraDistance){
    var difference = cameraDistance - curDistance;
    Transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Transform.position, Transform.position + new Vector3(0, difference, 0), Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `out hit` as the third parameter to [`Physics.Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), but the function signature is:

```
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float distance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers);
```

Effectively, you need to remove the `, out hit`, or change it to a float representing the maximum distance you want to ray test.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made it like this @Adam Harwood now, but it is vibrating when position is stabilized.

```
var hit : RaycastHit;
var curDistance : float;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.position, hit)){
    curDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, hit.point);
}

if(curDistance != cameraDistance){
    var difference = cameraDistance - curDistance;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, transform.position + new Vector3(0,difference,0), Time.deltaTime);
}
```